# Is there any way to tell Robocopy NOT to delete an empty folder after it has moved all files from it?

Tags: windows-7, robocopy

I have a folder that I dump files into which are later moved from there to another folder using Robocopy. After Robocopy empties the folder, it deletes it. How do I stop it from doing this?

Edit: Here's the command I was using

```
robocopy "F:\source" "F:\dest" *.avi *.webm *.mp4 *.mkv *.m4v /move /is /xx
```

Indeed, changing `/move` to `/mov` per the selected answer moved the files without deleting the empty folder.

Comment: Without the command you're using, it's not possible to definitively determine what the cause of your issue is _(@Anaksunaman's answer is the most probable issue you're having, but there's no way to definitively answer that with the information provided)_

Comment: @JW0914 Good call, I don't know why I didn't include it. Edited it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After Robocopy empties the folder, it deletes it. How do I stop it from doing this?

If you are using the `/move` option to copy files and directories, you can try using the `/s` and `/mov` options instead. This should move files (`/mov`), including in subdirectories (`/s`), without removing any directories in the source path (including the root directory itself) e.g.:

```
robocopy /s /mov ".\Source" ".\Destination"
```

Note that folders for files in the Source directory will be recreated in the Destination directory, with the appropriate files placed underneath them. If there are no subfolders in the Source directory, then you can simply use `/mov`.

Comment: Yep, you were right. Changing /move to /mov did the trick, so I no longer have to put a dummy file in there to keep the folder from being deleted. I edited the original command I used in my OP.